# I am trying to combine two tables (Master and child) into one. I need only one record of child table in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure for one record of a child table with in a Master table

I have Two Tables.

- Master "Property"
- Child  "PropertyImage"

I need all the details of `Property` with only one image.

In child table, one property may have many images.

```
Property (propertyId, title)

propertyImage (imageId, FK_propertyId, imageFile)
```

E.g.

```
property (1, smallbuilding)
property (2, largebuilding)

propertyImage(1, 1, 1.jpg)
propertyImage(2, 1, 2.jpg)
propertyImage(3, 1, 3.jpg)
propertyImage(4, 1, 4.jpg)
propertyImage(5, 2, 7.jpg)
propertyImage(6, 2, 8.jpg)
```

My requirement is:

```
MyProperty(propertyId, title, imageFile)
Myproperty(1, smallbuilding, 1.jpg)
Myproperty(2, bigbuilding, 2.jpg)
```

Comment: How do you want to pick the one `propertyImage` - the first by `imageId`? or perhaps something else?

Comment: Your expected result also doesnt make sense - property `2` is not associated with image `2.jpg` - the first one associated is `7.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sound like you need this

```
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY propertyId ORDER BY imageId) AS rn,
         propertyId, title, imageFile
  FROM Property p JOIN propertyImage pr ON p.propertyId = pr.FK_propertyId
  )
  SELECT propertyId, title, imageFile
  FROM cte
  WHERE rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank You @Alexander Fedorenko

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear. I think what you need is to `Merge two tables(propery,propertyImage) into a single table (myProperty)`. This sounds like a one off job, so why need a stored procedure? Following query can do the job. Please [check this MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) for stored procedure syntax if you need a one. Also note you should have a primary key column for your new MyProperty table.

```
INSERT INTO MyProperty (propertyId,title,imageFile)
SELECT propertyId, title, imageFile FROM (
    SELECT p.propertyId,p.title,i.imageFile, 
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY i.FK_propertyId, i.ImageId) RN
    FROM Property p JOIN propertyImage i 
     ON p.propertyId = i.FK_propertyId
) A
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: @PavanVParekh updated with `RANK()` to get the `TOP 1` based on `i.FK_propertyId, i.ImageId`

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you want to pick the one `propertyImage`, you could select one-per-property into a CTE and join that:

```
WITH FirstImagePerProperty
AS
(
    SELECT FK_propertyId,
           MIN(imageId) As FirstImageId
    FROM PropertyImage
    GROUP BY FK_propertyId
)
SELECT
   p.propertyId,
   p.title,
   i.imageId, 
   i.imageFile
FROM Property p
INNER JOIN FirstImagePerProperty fipp ON p.propertyId=fipp.FK_propertyId
INNER JOIN PropertyImage i ON fipp.FK_propertyId=i.FK_propertyId
```